# How to index column of composite types?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Given a multi dimensional composite type with 5 or more properties, each of which are numeric. I need to create an index which would allow me to query by any subset of those properties.

Example with a 3-D location vertex `X, Y, Z` (3 instead of 5 properties), I want to see for instance:

- all items on top of each other (`X=1 and Y=2 --Z doesn't matter`)
- all items at one height (`Z=3 --X and Y don't matter`)
- all items within a cube (`X between 10 and 20 and Y between 5 and 15 and Z between 1 and 5)`
- ...

I know postgres supports R-Trees but those are more suggested (only supported?) for 2-D special data. AFAIK B-Trees wouldn't really support those kind of queries, unless I create a B-Tree for every combination, or could postgres combine the indexes if I create one for `((column).X)` and another for `((column).Y)`?

The size of the table would be in short term, few million rows, possibly magnitudes more in long term.

**Update:**

After talking to a colleague I've realized now that what I'm asking for is more of a Data Warehouse solution with multidimensional cubes where you want to "cut" the data in "slices" to look at it form different sides, but maybe there is an answer to this.

Comment: "*or could postgres combine the indexes*" yes it can do that. But you need to check the execution plan to see whether it actually happens for your queries.